# Dynamic debugging with visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Hi I have two EXEs(**EXE1** and **EXE2**). In that **EXE1** will run **EXE2** at a specific interval. I need to debug **EXE2** while it is running.  How can I debug **EXE2** by attaching it with visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this can be achieved by placing the following code

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
```

before the code to debug of corresponding **EXEs**. 
When that **EXE** executed not under a debugger, a dialog will come up asking if you want to launch the debugger. Choose VS as your JIT (Just In Time) debugger and VS will start and you can single step or inspect your program’s execution at that line.

Be sure to remove any debug lines before deploying your program!

Answer (score 3):

You can set registry settings to start debugging immediately after your second exe starts.
Here is how to do on msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Open project with EXE2 code in Visual Studio. Once executable is started, attach to it's process from Visual Studio:

**Debug -> Attach to process**

Check 'Show processes from all users' (just in case). Find appropriate process by name and attach to it. That's it.